# Sequelize: Column not found immediately after creation

Tags: sequelize.js

In the same post route I am trying to create a new course and then SELECT that course via the findAll() method. I am doing this because I want to set the location header to the proper URI for the course that was jsut created. To do that, I need access to its id, which is auto generated. The problem is, when I call the findAll() method, it says the course I just created is not found.

```
app.post('/api/courses', async (req, res) => {
    try {

        const newCourse = req.body;


        await Course.create({
            title: newCourse.title,
            description: newCourse.description,
            estimatedTime: newCourse.estimatedTime,
            materialsNeeded: newCourse.materialsNeeded,
            userId: 1

        })
        const course = await Course.findAll({
            attributes: [newCourse.title]
        })


        res.location('/api/courses/' + course.id)
        res.status(201); 
    }catch(error) {
        console.warn(error);
    }

})

app.get('/api/courses/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const courseRequest = req.params.id;

        const course = await Course.findAll({
            where: {
                id: courseRequest
            },
            attributes: ['title', 'userId']
        })

         res.json({
            course
        }); 
    }catch(error) {
        console.error(error);
    }

})
```

UPDATE AFTER COMMENT BY Naor Levi
I logged the newly created course to the console and it returned the following:

```
Course {
  dataValues:
   { id: 11,
     title: 'Investing for beginners',
     description: 'Learn to invest your money wisely',
     estimatedTime: '3 weeks',
     materialsNeeded: 'pen and paper',
     userId: 1,
     updatedAt: 2020-01-13T23:50:53.748Z,
     createdAt: 2020-01-13T23:50:53.748Z },
  _previousDataValues:
   { title: 'Investing for beginners',
     description: 'Learn to invest your money wisely',
     estimatedTime: '3 weeks',
     materialsNeeded: 'pen and paper',
     userId: 1,
     id: 11,
     createdAt: 2020-01-13T23:50:53.748Z,
     updatedAt: 2020-01-13T23:50:53.748Z },
  _changed:
   { title: false,
     description: false,
     estimatedTime: false,
     materialsNeeded: false,
     userId: false,
     id: false,
     createdAt: false,
     updatedAt: false },
  _modelOptions:
   { timestamps: true,
     validate: {},
     freezeTableName: false,
     underscored: false,
     paranoid: false,
     rejectOnEmpty: false,
     whereCollection: null,
     schema: null,
     schemaDelimiter: '',
     defaultScope: {},
     scopes: {},
     indexes: [],
     name: { plural: 'Courses', singular: 'Course' },
     omitNull: false,
     sequelize:
      Sequelize {
        options: [Object],
        config: [Object],
        dialect: [SqliteDialect],
        queryInterface: [QueryInterface],
        models: [Object],
        modelManager: [ModelManager],
        connectionManager: [ConnectionManager],
        importCache: [Object] },
     hooks: {} },
  _options:
   { isNewRecord: true,
     _schema: null,
     _schemaDelimiter: '',
     attributes: undefined,
     include: undefined,
     raw: undefined,
     silent: undefined },
  isNewRecord: false }
Executing (default): SELECT `Investing for beginners` FROM `Courses` AS `Course`;
{ SequelizeDatabaseError: SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: Investing for beginners
```

It is telling me that the course I just created does not exist and I'm not sure why.

Comment: `Model.create` returns the created instance. Try to log the return value of `await Course.create` to see what is going on.

Comment: I tried what you said and posted the result above. If there is some helpful information in it I'm not sure what it is. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see under `dataValues` that a new row with `id: 11` has just been created.

Your problem is that `findAll` of `Sequelize.Model` returns an array of model instances and you tried to access a single instance.
Moreover, you had asked only for `title` attribute and right after that, you tried to access course.id. I.E even if you were accessing the return value of `findAll` correctly `id` propety woudn't be found at the result.

Try to fix your code according to the following example:

```js
app.post('/api/courses', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const newCourse = req.body;
        let course = await Course.create({
            title: newCourse.title,
            description: newCourse.description,
            estimatedTime: newCourse.estimatedTime,
            materialsNeeded: newCourse.materialsNeeded,
            userId: 1
        });

        // This is redundant and wrong.
        // const course = await Course.findAll({
        //    attributes: [newCourse.title]
        // })

        const courseParam = course.dataValues.id;
        res.location(`/api/courses/${courseParam}`);
        res.status(201); 
    }catch(error) {
        console.warn(error);
    }

});
```